# Setting a long sequence on a single line

Tags: math-mode

How to put an long exact sequence in a straight line. I wrote a code for the exact sequence  but it displays in 2 lines. Also I want to name the terms of the exact sequence as A, B, C, D below the `\underbrace`. How to do that:

```
$0 \rightarrow \underbrace{Ker(\phi) \otimes \Bbb{Q}_p \right} \rightarrow \underbrace{T(M)/I_{H_i}T(M) \otimes \Bbb{Q}_p}  
 \rightarrow \underbrace{M/I_{H_i} \otimes \Bbb{Q}_p}} \rightarrow \underbrace{M^{'}/I_{H_i}M^{'} \otimes \Bbb{Q}_p}} \rightarrow 0$
```

Comment: Please add a Minimum Working Example (MWE), beginning with `\documentclass`.  For example, I have no idea what `\Bbb` means without it.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much easier to debug code with a working minimal example rather than a code fragment.  The problem with your code is that you have a `\right}` that isn't matched and doesn't seem to do anything. The label for an underbrace is added with `_X` after the `\underbrace` argument.  Here is a fixed example.  I've also replaced `\Bbb` with `\mathbb` as the former command is deprecated.  AS egreg notes in the comment, the operator `\ker` should be used so that it is correctly rendered in `mathrm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\[ 0 \rightarrow \underbrace{\ker(\phi) \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p}_A 
      \rightarrow \underbrace{T(M)/I_{H_i}T(M) \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p}_B
%
 \rightarrow \underbrace{M/I_{H_i} \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p}_C 
 \rightarrow \underbrace{M^{'}/I_{H_i}M^{'} \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p}_D 
 \rightarrow 0
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: `\operatorname{Ker}` or the more widely used `\ker`.